# Logarithm properties doubt

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponentiation

The problem is $\log (5.64)^4$. According to the properties and laws of exponents, $\log (m^r) = r \log (m)$. But since the exponent is outside of the parenthesis in this problem, does it solves by like $4\log (5.64)$ or $(\log (5.64))^4$? TYIA.$ \ \ \ \ $

Answer (score 3):

@Ragnar has changed the statement of the problem. In the original problem, it is ambiguous. In the modified problem, it is clearly the case that the exponent is to be applied *after* the logarithm. $(\log 5.63)^4$ is not ambiguous, nor is $\log 5.63^4$ (in the second, the exponent is applied *before* the log). For that matter, $(\log(5.63))^4$ is not ambiguous. But $\log(5.63)^4$, **which is how the problem was originally stated**, is ambiguous, since it isn't clear whether you intend to treat the function as $\log$, with no parentheses (like $\sin$), or as $f(\cdot)$ like generic function names.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I have a sheet with logarithm problems. This is the only one that has an exponent outside the parenthesis, but I guess it is still ambiguous.

Comment: It really depends on how you usually write it. Does your instructor write $\log x$ or $\log(x)$?

Comment: I usually write it log(x), to avoid getting lost in the calculator, but most of my instructor's problems do not have parenthesis, and none, expect this one, are written this way.

Comment: In that case, I would say that it means the same thing as $\log (5.63^4)$ which could normally be written $\log 5.63^4$

Answer (score 1):

You're right that $\log(a^b)=b\log(a)$. Here, we have $(\log(a))^b$ indeed. This cannot be simplified easily. You could do the following, but I don't think that will help you:
$$
(\log(a))^2=\log(a)\log(a)=\log(a^{\log a})
$$
To calculate the answer, just calculate $\log 5.64$ and take the fourth power of that.

Comment: You have changed the intent of the OP's question, I think.

Comment: @MPW, You're probably right, I may have assumed one notation in my edit, where the question was which notation actually was used.

Comment: Thank you for answering! This is how I thought I'd solve the problem, until I read MPW's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer will not follow the law you have given. To see the difference, notice that $\log(5.63)$ represents the power of 10 needed to attain a result of $5.63$, i.e. it is the number (call it $a$ for short) that fits the equation $$10^a=5.63$$

Raising both sides to the fourth power gets $$(10^a)^4=5.63^4$$

Applying exponential rules gets $$10^{4a}=5.63^4$$

But remember that we let $a=\log(5.63)$. It follows from the above equation that, if raising $10$ to the power of $a$ gets $5.63$, then raising $10$ to the power of $4*a$ gets $5.63^4.$ That is, $$\log(5.63^4)=4a=4*\log(5.63)$$

Think about how this is different from your question, and you should clearly see why this rule won't apply for you. Your question is to solve $(\log(5.63))^4$. Here, following order of operations, you must first calculate $(\log(5.63)$ and then raise it to the fourth power, rather than first considering $5.63$ to the fourth power and then calculating logarithm as we did above. That is to say, using our earlier substitution for $a=\log(5.63)$, your solution is $a^4$ instead of $4a$.

Comment: My original post said it was log(5.64)^4, but it was edited. I couldn't tell if this meant log(5.64^4) or ((log(5.64))^4.